# How can I change the default order of Dock icons for new users?

Tags: plank, app-shortcuts

I plan to deploy elementary OS in a medium sized network environment, and wish to change the default config of the elementary desktop for newly created users, specifically the dock items. I've figured out how to add and remove default dock items via /etc/skel, but cannot seem to set the default order of the icons as they appear to the user. No matter what config files I copy over to the new user or /etc/skel, the icons must be manually dragged and dropped into their ideal positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dock (Plank) uses `dconf` to store its settings. You can find the items in the `net.launchpad.plank.docks` domain.

You can install `debconf-editor` to play around with things, and you can use the `gsettings` command-line tool to automate this.